# UIButton in between the UILabel text+iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uilabel

I want to implement a tagging feature in my application.

There is some text in the label on which I want to give the `UIButton` action event.

I had used this code to detect whether particular text is present in the `UILabel` or not.
How do I check if the particular text is present and if it gives the `UIButton` action event?

```
arr_count = {ABC,DEF,PQR};

FOR(int i = 0; i < [arr_Count]; i++) {
Nsstring *Str_dec1;
   NSRange range = [Str_dec1 rangeOfString:[arr_count objectatindex:i] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
   if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
       *******.....MISING CODE HERE......*****
   }
}
```

How should I code so that it gives me the `UIButton` action event when I click on ABC or PQR or DEF text in `UILabel`?

Comment: The code `[arr_Count; i++]` inside your `for` block looks strange to me (I confess, I don't know cocoa so I could be wrong). How do the square brackets work in there?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the label to call the `UIButton` method. Or you could do something like:

```
 if(condition)
 {
     [self callButtonEvent:sender] // sender can be nil if you aren't passing anything
 }
```

where  `condition` is when you check if your label's text is equal to whatever string you want.

Comment: .I want to call the method only when user tab on the particular text area in the label.To to detect that XYZ come to the particular area in the label

Answer (score 0):

you can simply call

```
[self yourButtonActionMethod:nil];
```